# unorderable types: int() > range()

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a task of creating battleships in Python, when the user inputs co-ordinates out of the 5x5 grid, I want a pop up stating it is out of range. My problem is I get an error message stating "unorderable types: int() > range()", I'm new to Python so I do not know what that means.

```
if guess_row == ship_row and guess_col == ship_col:
    print ("Congratulations, you sank my battleship!")
else:
    if guess_row > range(5) or guess_col > range(5):
        print ("Out of Range!")
    else:
        print ("You missed my battleship")
        grid[guess_row][guess_col]="X"
        print_grid(grid)
```

Comment: You want `if guess_row not in range(5)`. Range returns an iterable, not a number.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you so much :D

Answer (score 1):

`range(5)` is a range (actually it's the list `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]`), not a number. How can a number be greater than a range? It can't, hence the error.

These will work and are all equivalent:

- `guess_row not in range(5)`
- `guess_row not in range(0, 5)`
- `not (0 <= guess_row < 5)`
- `not (0 <= guess_row <= 4)`
- `guess_row < 0 or guess_row >= 5`
- `guess_row < 0 or guess_row > 4`

Comment: The message is from 3.x.  In 2.x the comparison would be valid.  In 3.x, range is an immutable arithmetic sequence object, but answer is otherwise correct.